# $(select).val().length of null gives error

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select

I have a select object in my form, styled using Bootstrap-select.js plug-in. When I initialize the select box, and I try to get the value of it, it is `null` until I select an option. In my script I am using:-

`$(select).val().length`

However, this gives an error when `$(select).val()` is `null`. I would really like to get a `0`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is `select` a variable? its used like one `$(select)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:-

```
($(select).val() || '').length
```

> [**Logical Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)
>
> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values.
>   When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and ||
>   operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands,
>   so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may
>   return a non-Boolean value.
>
> Examples of expressions that can be converted to false are:
>
> - null
> - NaN
> - 0
> - empty string ("")
> - NaN
> - undefined

**Demo**

```js
var length = ($('select').val() || '').length;

console.log('length: ' + length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>

<select>
```

Comment: That's just awesome and clever. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
var $selectElement = $("#mySelect");
var len = $selectElement.val() != null ? $selectElement.val().length : 0;
console.log(len);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function get_length( select ){
 if ( $(select).val() != null ) {
  return $(select).val().length;
 }else{
  return 0;
 }
}
```

`console.log( get_length(my_select_box_variable) );`

Comment: That's not the issue. I am using something like this: `var $selectElement = $("#mySelect"); console.log($selectElement.val().length);`

Comment: you could simplify your function further like this - `function get_length(select) {
  return $(select).val() != null ? $(select).val().length : 0;
}`